# How to get notified about logon/logoff and display lock/unlock

Tags: bash

We need to monitor user idle time in our organization. Please help us how to get logon, logoff, lock, unlock time.

Thanks.

Comment: You will find your users will hesitate to lock or log off, compromising security.

Answer (score 0):

Capture login: Place a script file in the path

```
"/etc/init.d/Login.sh"
```

Make the file executable

```
chmod +x Login.sh
```

Capture logoff: Place a script file in the path

```
"/etc/profile.d/LogOff.sh"
```

Make the file executable

```
chmod +x LogOff.sh
```

Capturing Lock and UnLock

```
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 | 
  while read x; do 
    case "$x" in 
        LockHint) 
          if [[ "$x" == "$lock" ]] ; then 
             echo "lock" 
          fi 
          if [[ "$x" == "$unLock" ]] ; then 
             echo "UnLock" 
          fi 
     ;; 
   esac
```